# XML request sent as null on server via soap

Tags: php, xml, soap

My code

```
$xml="<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/envelope/'>
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<FlightAvailability xmlns=''>
<strUserId>asd</strUserId>
<strPassword>asdf</strPassword>
<strAgencyId>dfs</strAgencyId>
<strSectorFrom>sdf</strSectorFrom>
<strSectorTo>PKRdsf</strSectorTo>
</FlightAvailability>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
$client = new SoapClient('wsdl');

$result = $client->FlightAvailability($xml);
```

But Server is receiving null value.

strUserID=null strPassword=null strAgencyId=null strSectorFrom=n
ull strSectorTo=null strFlightDate=null strReturnDate=null
strTripType=null strNationality=null intAdult=null intChild=null